# How can I check if a user exists with PDO?

Tags: php, mysql

My PDO query is not working for some reason, the page itself doesn't seem to have any error, I've been trying to fix this for like 2 months and nothing worked, I got this "final" code which not seems to have any errors and it's still not working.

```
<?php
require 'database.php';

$message = '';

if (!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['phone']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {
  $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, email, phone, password) VALUES (:username, :email, :phone, :password)";
  $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->bindParam(':username', $_POST['username']);
  $stmt->bindParam(':email', $_POST['email']);
  $stmt->bindParam(':phone', $_POST['phone']);
  $password = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
  $stmt->bindParam(':password', $password);

  $query = $con->prepare("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = :username");
  $query->bindParam(':username', $_POST['username']);
  $query->execute();

  if($query->rowCount() > 0){
    ?> Este usuario ya existe <?php
  } 
  else {
    if($stmt->execute()) {
      header('Location: login.php');
    }
    else {
      echo "Ocurrió un error";
    }
  }
  }
?>
```

Comment: You do not execute the first query? There is prepare and bind param, but no execution?

Comment: I did, check the code again.

Comment: @Playerl Can you please explain where in the code you have here are you executing the first query? Of course you are executing the second query(which is responsible for finding the user) but the first query(which is responsible for inserting the record in db) you are not executing it.

Comment: else {
    if($stmt->execute()) {
      header('Location: login.php');
    }

Comment: OK, my mistake, so can you please elaborate on what do you mean by saying "My PDO query is not working for some reason"? Do you mean the record is not inserted in the db?

Comment: So you have two different connection defined in database.php? 1: `$conn` and 2: `$con` ?

Comment: Wait, I didn't realize that. I actually misspelled the $conn variable, now it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that it's because you have used a inapropriate variable. 
in initialisation of $stmt you used `$conn` and in $query you used `$con`
make sure to the rigth varaible